# Texture brightness problem in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, image, color

Currently using 2.83 (supposedly latest version).

When I add an image as plane (leaves for my tree), its colour is very pale/bright. This looks alright in Eevee but looks horrible in most other render options (such as Cycles) that I have available. (BTW, if I export my tree model to UE4, which version will be used? The Eevee or Cycles one?) Can someone please help? Will provide whatever information is necessary to have this problem solved.

[image: Cycles]

[image: Eevee]

Comment: it might be the Render > Color Management? or the lighting?

Comment: How bright things are depends on the intensity of the lights and environment.

Comment: I did search in the Color Management and tried different stuff, but didnt notice any improvement. Anything a bit more specific?
@susu But why is it normal in Eevee and this bright in Cycles? It is the same light with the same intensity....

Comment: could you please pack the image and share your file? The renders will be different in Eevee and Cycles, so Cycles may need some adjusments

Comment: Couldn't find an option to upload directly here, so used a fileshare site:
https://gofile.io/d/obZDgy

Advice is appreciated.